m3u playlist vlc streaming issue, and python script shows not working
so I recently stuck in a issue. I am working on an iptv project the streams are yet not public. we have 4 different systems. but when we test udp links on each of system all system didnt get any stream only a single system get stream. yesterday I create a python script that can test the m3u streams. but on every channel it says that not working on same system. can someone help me in this regards,
i try 4 system and 3 of them are not playin streams in vlc and when i try to run python script on same pc that run vlc streams it shows error that stream is not working. mostly of the streams is working it is hard to check each streams. help me to ensure that script are working so i didnt need to run each vlc stream everytime.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
